# Adjusting all depth data in a file by some elevation

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, file

The code adds up numbers from two different text files. It opens an input file 'DEPTH.dat' and reads the numbers after some headers as follows:

> ```
> SCALAR
> ND    3
> ST    0
> TS    1000
> 1.0
> 1.0
> 1.0
> SCALAR
> ND    3
> ST    0
> TS    2000
> 3.3
> 3.4
> 3.5
> SCALAR
> ND    3
> ST    0
> TS    3000
> 1.7
> 1.8
> 1.9
> ```

It then adds to them numbers which have been read from a smaller text file 'ELEVATION.dat' which looks as follows:

> ```
> SCALAR
> ND    3
> ST    0
> TS    0
> 10.0
> 10.0
> 10.0
> ```

The result is written in a text file 'output.txt' like this:

> ```
> SCALAR
> ND    3
> ST    0
> TS    1000
> 11.0
> 11.0
> 11.0
> SCALAR
> ND    3
> ST    0
> TS    2000
> 13.3
> 13.4
> 13.5
> SCALAR
> ND    3
> ST    0
> TS    3000
> 11.7
> 11.8
> 11.9
> ```

---

Here's the code in question.  As I have learned from 200_success in [my last code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/145815/23788) that I should write the code using functions, I tried to write this new code using some functions.

For a small example, the code works properly but for bigger input data, it does not work. (For a 350 MB file with 30 million lines, there is no response after two hours.)  How can the code be improved?

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(iterable, n, padvalue=None):
    return zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=padvalue)


def writing_ND(f1):
    for line1 in f1:
        if line1.startswith('ND'):
            ND = float(line1.split()[-1])
            return ND


def writing_TS(f):
    with open(f, 'r') as f:
        for line1 in f:
            if line1.startswith('TS'):
                x = float(line1.split()[-1])
                TS.append(x)
        return TS
TS = []
ND = []
n = 0
add_numbers = []
TS = writing_TS('DEPTH.dat')
with open("ELEVATION_LHP.dat") as f, open("DEPTH.dat") as f1,\
     open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    ND = writing_ND(f)
    n = int(ND)+4
    f.seek(0)
    for lines in grouper(f, int(n)):
        for item in lines[4:]:
            add_numbers.append(float(item))
    i = 0
    for l in grouper(f1, n):
        data_numbers = []
        for line in l[4:]:
            data_numbers.append(float(line.split()[-1].strip()))
            result_numbers = [x + y for x, y in zip(data_numbers, add_numbers)]
        del data_numbers
        out.write('SCALAR\nND    %d\nST  0\nTS      %0.2f\n' % (ND, TS[i]))
        i += 1
        for item in result_numbers:
            out.write('%s\n' % item)
```

Comment: I don't get it. When I run your code, it completes in minutes, not hours. Is there something horribly slow with your hardware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Minor issues

You have some minor funny business going on:

- Repurposing `f` in `writing_TS()` makes the code harder to follow:

  > ```
  > with open(f, 'r') as f:
  > ```
- In `writing_TS()`, you do

  > ```
  > TS.append(x)
  > ```

  … where you are modifying `TS`, which is a global variable.  But then you `return TS` as well, which makes it pointless to communicate via a global variable.
- On the other hand, you also have a global variable `ND`, which is initially an empty list, but becomes a `float`, but you actually want it to be an `int`.  But why bother initializing `n = 0` at all?

### Performance

Your `ELEVATION.dat` is a small file, and your `DEPTH.dat` is a huge file.  So **don't process `DEPTH.dat` twice!**  You want to run through `DEPTH.dat` linearly, in a single pass.

When performance is a problem, just keep it as simple as possible.  The core of the solution should "ideally" resemble this:

```
with open('DEPTH.dat') as depth, open('OUTPUT.dat', 'w') as out:
    for line in depth:
        out.write(line)
```

Of course, that doesn't do anything useful — it just copies the file line by line.  But it gives you the outline of the code to strive for, and it also establishes a lower bound on the running time.  (Try it.  If you aren't satisfied with the performance, then you know that your task cannot be accomplished satisfactorily using Python.)

With that in mind, how can we modify the skeleton to actually do the work?  I would make two assumptions:

- `DEPTH.dat` consists of repeated blocks resembling the structure of `ELEVATION.dat`.
- The lines of `DEPTH.dat` should be copied verbatim, except the numeric lines, which should be summed with their counterpart in `ELEVATION.dat`.

Here is how I would express those two ideas in code:

```
import itertools

def read_elevation(filename):
    """
    Read elevation data.  Lines in the file that consist only of a float are
    converted to a float; all other lines are preserved.
    """
    def try_parse_float(line):
        try:
            return float(line)
        except ValueError:
            return line

    with open(filename) as f:
        return [try_parse_float(line) for line in f]


elevation_cycle = itertools.cycle(read_elevation('ELEVATION_LHP.dat'))
with open('DEPTH.dat') as depth, \
     open('OUTPUT.dat', 'w') as out:
    for depth_line, elev in zip(depth, elevation_cycle):
        if isinstance(elev, float):
            print(elev + float(depth_line), file=out)
        else:
            out.write(depth_line)
```

This is simpler than your original code, in that I'm not trying as hard to "make sense" of the data by parsing `ND`.  It's not assuming that there are four header lines per group, namely `SCALAR`, `ND`, `ST`, and `TS`.  There isn't even any grouping involved: it just blindly assumes that `DEPTH.dat` contains many repetitions of blocks resembling `ELEVATION.dat`.

Comment: This solution completes in a couple of minutes on my machine.

Comment: My mind is  not so organized as your mind. Thanks a lot. It works now.

Answer (score 3):

Well that's a lot of input data, but also the processing isn't super
optimised, so I'm not that surprised it takes a bit long.

For the start I'd like to clean up a bit, `writing_ND` and `writing_TS`
should be similar and probably do the `seek` call in the functions, so
I'd suggest something like the following:

```
def writing_ND(f):
    try:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('ND'):
                return float(line.split()[-1])
    finally:
        f.seek(0)


def writing_TS(f):
    result = []
    try:
        return [float(line.split()[-1])
                for line in f if line.startswith('TS')]
    finally:
        f.seek(0)
```

Note the addition of `try/finally` to always reset the file back to the
start and the use of a list comprehension to make the loop more
compact.

For the main function (well, "function", there's no `main` right now)
I'd suggest moving variables close to their usage and to not "declare"
variables like `ND`, `TS` and `n` like that, just assign them on first
use with the correct values:

```
with open('ELEVATION_LHP.dat') as f, open('DEPTH.dat') as f1, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    ND = writing_ND(f)
    TS = writing_TS(f1)
    n = int(ND) + 4
```

Of course `f` and `f1` aren't so great names.  The next loop looks okay:

```
add_numbers = []
for lines in grouper(f, n):
    for item in lines[4:]:
        add_numbers.append(float(item))
```

`i` shouldn't be necessary, using `enumerate` is clearer.  The
indentation for `result_numbers` is probably wrong, otherwise the
repeated calls are unnecessary.  I'd probably also try not to construct
the intermediate lists for `data_numbers` or `result_numbers` - while
that's nice for readability it'll produce some garbage and therefore
will take more time.  Maybe start with this:

```
for i, l in enumerate(grouper(f1, n)):
    out.write('SCALAR\nND    %d\nST  0\nTS      %0.2f\n' % (ND, TS[i]))
    for line, number in zip(l[4:], add_numbers):
        out.write('%s\n' % (float(line.split()[-1].strip()) + number))
```

Lastly, for `grouper` I'd remove the `padvalue` parameter as it's
unused (shouldn't this be in a library somewhere anyway?)

---

At this point I'd suggest to take a profiler and measure where exactly
most of the time is taken.  As a *really* simple thing while developing
I'd even just add a progress output say every thousand input records or
so, simply to have some idea about whether the program is actually
progressing or not.

I imagine the line splitting, float conversion, or output formatting
might be part of the problem.  There are a couple of routes to take
afterwards, mostly by avoiding work, or replacing convenient functions
(`split`) with manual work.

---

Lastly, this approach seems, while working, a bit complicated.  Is there
no way that you can use a more compact format, or keep the values
in-memory for later processing?  Especially having a single pandas data
frame (or NumPy even) makes life much easier if you can stay in Python.

Comment: `grouper` is an [`itertools` recipe in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). @Mohamad should have noted so in a comment.

Comment: I know :) I hate the copy&paste though.